# Long Long int trims numbers less than it`s assumed 64bit capacity?

Tags: c

I have a question about a program which generate Fibonacci numbers. The user enters the number of Fibonacci numbers he/she need , and the program generates it. The problem is *after 48 numbers the program start to give wrong numbers. It seems to do trimming to numbers giving out some random results*. I made an array of "unsigned long long int" that is 64 bits for each number. It should carry big numbers, but it didn`t.

Here is my code :

```
‪#‎include‬ <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
 int n , i ;
 printf("Enter number of Fibonacci numbers you need : ");
 scanf("%d" , &n);

 unsigned long long int fib_numbers[n];

 fib_numbers[0] = 0 ;
 printf("1. %llu\n",0);
 fib_numbers[1] = 1 ;
 printf("2. %llu\n",1);

 for(i=2;i<n;i++)
   {
    fib_numbers[i]=fib_numbers[i-1]+fib_numbers[i-2];
    printf("%d. %llu\n",i+1,fib_numbers[i]);
   }
 return 0;
}
```

Hers is a snap for output, notice number 49

[image]

Comment: Looks like a **32bit** overflow...

Comment: Can't reproduce http://ideone.com/YqRaOw

Comment: You are not using 16-bit Turbo-C++ or anything, are you?

Comment: Try `printf("%d\n", (int) sizeof (unsigned long long int));` and see if you get 4 or 8 or ?

Comment: Don't post images instead of text!

Comment: it is  `8 bytes` , and i am not using `16 bit turbo c++`

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a problem with the underlying libraries not supporting a 64bit unsigned long long. Your code works perfectly on my 64bit Linux system.

```
48. 2971215073
49. 4807526976
50. 7778742049
51. 12586269025
52. 20365011074
53. 32951280099
54. 53316291173
55. 86267571272
56. 139583862445
57. 225851433717
58. 365435296162
59. 591286729879
60. 956722026041
```

As for a solution, that depends on your platform, compiler, etc. Not enough info to guide. However, you might want to look into a system that supports larger numbers, as 64bits only covers up to fib 94. [The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](http://gmplib.org/) might do what you need for longer runs, and may automatically correct for the lack of precision in your libraries as well.

Comment: If they don't support `long long` data types, why would it compile?

Comment: If you don't have your compiler set to strict, this probably only shows up as a warning.

Answer (score -1):

You can determine the maximum value of an object of type `unsigned long long int` the following way

```
#include <limits>

//...

std::cout << std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long int>::max() << std::endl;
```

You can compare the value with the values of the Fibonacci numbers you get.

Or in C you can use constant `ULLONG_MAX` declared in header `<limits.h>`

Maybe the reason is that the function `printf` of your compiler does not support format specifier `%llu`

You can also try to use macro `PRIu64` that might be declared in header `<inttypes.h>`.

For example

```
#include <inttypes.h>

//...

printf("%d. %" PRIu64 "\n",i+1,fib_numbers[i]);
```

Comment: Isn't `unsigned long long int` guaranteed to hold at least 2^64-1? No reason for a 32bit problem.

Comment: @deviantfan It is only guaranteed that long long is wider or equal to long.:) But you can use specific types like uint_64 declared in header <stdint.h> in C or <cstdint> in C++.

Comment: deviantfan is correct in that `long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64-bits. You can google this if you are really unsure.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow But `uint_64` is not guarantied to be defined. Is it?

Comment: @Vlad Then whats about eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be and it's references

Comment: @NeilKirk You are write. The C STandard guarantees that long long is at least 64 bits.

Comment: @deviantfan It seems that your printf does not support %llu format specifier.

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский Yes, these types are optional.

Comment: @chux Thanks. I never used these macros myself.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow What does my printf have to do with anything? (I'm not the OP, if you think that)

Comment: @deviantfan I made a mistake.:) Nevertheless you can try your printf.:)